# Jumping car battery

Tags: battery

Donor cables hooked up correctly, while the receiving car cables were reversed. It didn't start, but smoked instead. Mechanic shop used a portable jumper, then used receiving car again and had cables reversed. Again it smoked and didn't start.  Then a friend checked and said alternator fuse had blown. They replaced it with a 75A instead off 100A fuse with instructions to replace right away back to the normal amperage fuse. They checked the battery and alternator with machine and they checked out ok. I took the car to a shop and replaced alternator fuse and radio fuse. They said the battery was shorted and alternator was no good. Is this possible with regard to battery and alternator?

Comment: I have read and re- read this question but can't figure out what you are asking. Can you edit to clarify what the question is?

Comment: Please ask a real question that we can understand!

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible to burn out the alternator and battery by hooking the jumper box (or jumper cables) up backwards. The alternator can fry rather quickly (diodes will fry and the alternator becomes useless). The battery can take longer.

Basically when you hook a battery up in series (backwards) instead of parallel (normal), you create a circuit. This will not only create sparks, it generates a lot of heat which you'll figure out *very quickly* through the jumper cables. Putting them on backwards can fry the battery if left there long enough.